# How can I correct the routing error in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I always get routing errors in this Ruby file on Rails to project. It shows me routing error as you can see in below screenshot.

All gems are installed properly it shows me the home page but do not show me the check file or show file page.

Here is my Routes.rb code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/submission3'
  post 'home/checkFile'
  get 'home/showFiles'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
```

Here is an image of the error shown:

[image]

Here is my controller code:

```
# C:\Users\attari\RubymineProjects\submission3\app\controllers\home_controller.rb
require 'docx'
require 'find'
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def submission3

  end
  def checkFile
    word = params[:folder][:word]
    path = params[:folder][:path]
    @files = checkWord(word, path)
    puts "FILES ARE #{@files}"
    redirect_to home_showFiles_path(@files)
    # puts "WORD IS #{word} PATH IS #{path}"
  end
  def save
    @submissions = submission3.new
  end
  def checkWord(userInput, folderInput)
    count = 0
    if (Dir.exist?(folderInput))
      docx_file_paths = []
      filtered_files = []
      Find.find(folderInput) do |path|
        docx_file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\.docx$/
      end
      (0..docx_file_paths.length - 1).each { |i|
        d = Docx::Document.open(docx_file_paths[i])
        d.each_paragraph do |p|
          string_ = p.to_s()
          if (string_.include? userInput)
            puts docx_file_paths[i]
            filtered_files.append(docx_file_paths[i])
            count = count + 1
            puts count
          else
            puts "No word Matched"
          end
        end
        puts count
      }
      return filtered_files
    else
      puts "No Directory exist"
    end
  end
  def create
    @submission3 = submission3.new(params[:word])
    if @submission3.save
      redirect_to new_submission_path
    end
  end
  private
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title)
  end
end
```

How can I fix this routes.rb error?

Comment: I can share my full project zip file if you ask me Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the error message, you can see that the filename is being appended directly to the route name (`/home/showFiles.C:%5CUsers...`). You need to add an id to the route so that Rails knows to expect something there. Your route should look something like this:

```rb
get 'home/show_files/:file_name'
```

[Note that you need to define `:file_name` in the context where this will be accessed (your controller).]

Even better would be to use a model as the basis for your route. So, if you have (for example) a File model, you would use:

```rb
resources :files
```

and Rails will generate a whole pile of routes for you automatically (or you can limit the routes by doing something like `resources :files, only: [:show, :index, :create, :delete]`).

Basically, I think you need to read up more on how Rails, and routes specifically, are supposed to work. [RailsGuides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) is probably a good place to start. If you work *with* Rails and its conventions, you'll find your life a lot easier! Rails prefers convention over configuration!

Also, on a side issue, you're not following Rails convention in naming your methods and variables. CamelCase is used in object names (like `class HomeController`) but not method names or variable names - Rails uses snake_case for these. Again, if you stick to Rails convention (`show_files` not `showFiles`, for example), you'll find things go a lot smoother. Following the Rails conventions means Rails will seamlessly stitch things together for you; fail to follow them and Rails will be a complete nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you are trying to access `/submission3` route even though you have defined `/home/submission3` route. Updating the route should fix your routing error.

Comment: how to update it bro can you please help with that